# Entity Framework Why Add Entity "User" And Property "CreateUser" Got Error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This common model, although the following error will occur, but does not affect the Build!

Error       1      Error 6029: The member '**CreateUser**' on the type '**Model1.User**' conflicts with the generated factory method.    d:\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\Model1.edmx    1      1      ClassLibrary1

But Build succeeded

Is this is a bug?

Comment: Isn't this Resharper or similar library error? When you create EF diagram from generator, there is `CreateType()` static function created for every `Type`. You probably overloaded it, but it shouldn't be error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well. The issue was that I had a User table that contained a CreateUser column. Changing the column name to CreatedBy worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen weird conflicts like this happen when I've made several changes to the underlying data store and regenerated the model multiple times.  Deleting the EF model from my project and recreating it usually fixes it.

Comment: My situation is very simple use, as long as the above situation will have the error, regardless of renewed several times.The point is, why this error occurs, the build was successful.